# Android Studio, Parse.com, custom adapter, cannot resolve symbol

Tags: parse-platform, syntax-error

I am new in creating apps. I am learning by doing courses on Udemy. So right now I am learning how to create a simple app where your can register, login and post a message, and I am doing all of this using `Parse.com`. Everything worked perfectly until today, when it was time to create a custom adapter that shows these posts.

The error is: `cannot resolve symbol mStatus` in the `HomepageActivity` class, though in the Udemy video, everything works perfectly.

Another strange error is in the line

`ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery <ParseObject> ("Status");`

the second `<ParseObject>` is greyed out and it says Explicit type argument can be replaced with `<>`, though in the video its white(working).

The only explanation I thought of is that the video is old and something changed in the syntax, but I am not that great of a programmer to understand what to do. Or maybe im doing something wrong? Please help.

P.S . when I am trying to run the app, I am getting this message:

`Note:C:\Users\User\AndroidStudioProjects\LiveUpdate\app\src\main\java\com\mycompany\liveupdate\StatusAdapter.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations`.

Here is the adapter code:

```
package com.mycompany.liveupdate;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.parse.ParseObject;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by User on 2015-01-18.
 */
public class StatusAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    protected Context mContext;
    protected List<ParseObject> mStatus;

    public StatusAdapter(Context context, List status) {
        super(context, R.layout.homepagecustomlayout, status);
        mContext = context;
        mStatus = status;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(
                    R.layout.homepagecustomlayout, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.usernameHomepage = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.usernameHP);
            holder.statusHomepage = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.statusHP);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {

            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        }

        ParseObject statusObject = mStatus.get(position);

        // title
        String username = statusObject.getString("user");
        holder.usernameHomepage.setText(username);

        // content
        String status = statusObject.getString("newStatus");
        holder.statusHomepage.setText(status);

        return convertView;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        TextView usernameHomepage;
        TextView statusHomepage;

    }

}
```

Here is the code, where im trying to call this adapter:

```
package com.mycompany.liveupdate;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.parse.FindCallback;
import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseQuery;
import com.parse.ParseUser;

import java.util.List;


public class HomepageActivity extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_homepage);
        Parse.initialize(this, "uinXCHcfbdm8zrbUT9y8Vu4R2qU5D22FZwkHs5HZ", "v1PL4oDu3ebtSidJFhjWRkkBQVAD8sefIB1WDFeq");

        ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
        if (currentUser != null) {
            // show user the homepage
            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Status");
            query.orderByDescending("createdAt");
            query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                @Override
                public void done(List<ParseObject> status, ParseException e) {
                    if(e == null){
                        //success

                       mStatus = status;

                        StatusAdapter adapter = new StatusAdapter(getListView().getContext(), status);
                        setListAdapter(adapter);


                    }else {
                        //there was a problem
                    }
                }
            });


        } else {
            // show the signup or login screen

            Intent takeUserToLogin = new Intent(HomepageActivity.this, LogInActivity.class);
            startActivity(takeUserToLogin);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_homepage, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        switch (id){
            case R.id.updateStatus:
                //take user to updatestatus activity
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, UpdateStatusActivity.class );
                startActivity(intent);

                break;
            case R.id.logoutUser:
// log out user
                ParseUser.logOut();

                // take the user back to logout screen
                Intent takeUserToLogin = new Intent(this, LogInActivity.class);
                startActivity(takeUserToLogin);
                break;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your haven't define the type of mStatus. However you don't seem to use it in your homeActivity anyway,  so in your homeactivity comment out the linke mStatus = status;..Let me know if that fixes it

Comment: I am facing same problem. Let me how to fix it?